# Split content into multiple file

Tags: awk, split, grep

I have following content of file `text.txt`

```
bla,one,bla
bla,two,bla
bla,one,bla
bla,one,bla
```

I would like to key off 2nd field and split content into following files:

```
# One.txt
bla,one,bla
bla,one,bla
bla,one,bla
```

And

```
#Two.txt:
bla,two,bla
```

Comment: Have you tried something and stuck at somewhere. You can do this by output redirection within `awk` command.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85585/split-the-content-of-a-file-in-linux and http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/06/awk-10-examples-to-split-file-into.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be very easily done using redirections within an `awk` script

```
awk -F, '{print > ($2".txt")}'
```

**Example**

```
$ awk k -F, '{print > ($2".txt")}' file

$ cat one.txt
bla,one,bla
bla,one,bla
bla,one,bla

$ cat two.txt
bla,two,bla
```

---

- `print` by default prints the current input line.
- `> $2".txt"` Redirects the print output to the a file with second column as its name.
- It would be a good idea to close the files as well, so that we don't end up with too many opened file descriptors, Just in case the input file is too big.

  ```
  close($2."txt")
  ```